# Find remainder in bash

Tags: bash, shell

A codechef problem:

> Write a program to find the remainder when an integer A is divided by an integer B.
>
> ###### Input
>
> The first line contains an integer T, the total number of test cases. Then T lines follow, each line contains two Integers A and B.
>
> ###### Output
>
> For each test case, find the remainder when A is divided by B, and display it in a new line.
>
> ###### Constraints
>
> - 1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
> - 1 ≤ A,B ≤ 10000

This is my solution. It works with the sample numbers but when I submit it it fails a test. I'm pretty sure the code is correct. What might the problem be?

```
#!/bin/bash
read T
var0=0

while [[ "$var0" < "$T" ]]
do

read A B

echo $(( A % B ))

(( var0++ ))
done
```

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)

Comment: please expand on what *`it fails a test`* means ... generates and error? no output? wrong output? hangs? something else?

Comment: `<` should be `-lt`. `<` is lexicographic comparison, `-lt` is numeric comparison.

Comment: please update the question with a sample input file, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output; also update the question with an example invocation of the script

Comment: @markp-fuso He almost certainly doesn't know that, it's being rejected by a code competition site.

Comment: You probably didn't use a large enough value of `$T` to notice the problem.

Comment: @Barmar thank you it work did not know < doesn't work for integers.

Comment: depends on how you're performing the comparison ... `[ $x -lt $y ]`, `[[ $x -lt $y ]]`, `(( x < y ))`

Comment: Works fine.  I copied your code.  Here are my results:  '3
1 3
1
2 3
2
4 3
1'

Comment: `while ((var0 < T))` is the way of the future.

Comment: @markp-fuso yes but idk why i thought you can use <> in the test command to compare integers.

Comment: @RichardJessop provide your inputs for that set of output; try `20` and 5 copies of `1 1`; the script (as is) will stop printing results after the 3rd set of output because `3` (string) is *not*`<` `20` (string)

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @Cyrus no need i used -lt instead of < and it worked.

Comment: To be on-topic here, a question needs to be about a _specific failure_. Not "it failed a test", but a precise, specific problem. (Yes, the OP may not know what the specific problem is, but that doesn't change the topicality guidelines).

Comment: `[[ "$var0" < "$T" ]]` is doing a lexicographic comparision. You want numeric comparision. Do a `while (( var0 < T ))` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine under specific conditions not explained here.  I copied it, saved it to rem.bash, changed the permission to make it executable, and ran it.  The following is the session result:

```
$ rem.bash
3
1 3
1
2 3
2
4 3
1
```

The first 3 is the number of times to run the operation.  I then entered: 1 3.  The remainder is output as 1.  On the third iteration, I entered: 4 3.  The remainder is 1.  The loop exited, and the program terminated.

To make it work for all inputs, change the while line to

`while ((var0 < t))`

In bash arithmetic, stuff between (( and )), you don't need $ to dereference the variable.  You can also use standard relational operators.

Comment: i used -lt as suggest in the comments and it worked.

Comment: Here is the link about Shell Arithmetic which gives data about `(( ))`: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html